# AC Voltage Detector with MID400 optocoupler

Tags: raspberry-pi, opto-isolator

The task I am trying to achieve is as follows: I am using a MID400 optocoupler to send either a 5V or 0V signal to a pi plate depending on if there is AC voltage present. I am using 120V AC from a wall outlet on the left side of the chip. In addition, I am supplying 5V DC from the raspberry pi to the right side of the chip. More specifically these are the conditions I would like to meet:

1) If there is AC voltage present, the chip should send a logical low (0V) voltage to the pi plate.

2) If there is NO AC voltage present, the 5V DC supplied from the pi should output to the pi plate.

I am using a 22k ohm resistor with one AC connection into pin 3. The other AC connection is inserted to pin 1. And I am using a 300 ohm resistor that is inserted to pin 6 and pin 8. **I am following exactly as the datasheet calls for**, but it is not working as expected. When I first tested it with just the 5V and no AC input, the circuit outputted the 5V as expected, but when I attached the 120V, the output voltage did not change to 0V. It may be a problem with my grounding, but I can't determine if that is the case. I will link the datasheet(circuit I built is Figure 4 on page 7) and my schematic I built. Any tips would be appreciated.

https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MI/MID400.pdf

[image: Updated circuit]

[image: schematic]

Comment: Don't describe your circuit. Don't show a picture of a breadboard version when a schematic diagram is the requirement to make sense of your question.

Comment: You have both ends of that resistor connected to pin 3. It's not 'in series' with anything. And as a result your opto is probably smoked.

Comment: The title says you want to detect voltage, the body says you want to detect current ….which is it??

Comment: There is a circuit drawing tool built into electronics.stackexchange - use it, and you'll get much better answers

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry, I removed the photo and added my schematic

Comment: @Oliver Done! Any thoughts?

Comment: @brhans I am just following the schematic on the datasheet, why would that fry the opto?

Comment: You have no current through the input LEDs.  Connect pin 1 to the AC Live, and pin 3, through the resistor, to AC Neutral.

Comment: @peterbennett That is what I did, but I did not label that on the schematic but I fixed it.

Comment: *"it is not working as expected"* = unknown to everyone but you.

Comment: @andyaka Added some more details regarding the testing

Comment: You show the power supply to pin 8 as negative - it must be positive, +5V.

Comment: Because you didn't follow the schematic in the datasheet. You have that resistor connected with both of its legs shorted together. Look at the layout of a breadboard - all 5 of those holes in each row are connected to each other.

Comment: - and I re-added the photo back into your question since it shows this important error.

Comment: @brhans That makes sense! Is this modified breadboard what you were thinking of? Then the Neutral AC input would go into the "-" rail?

Comment: yes - much better. What you have there now follows the schematic and *should* work - if you haven't killed the opto by applying the full mains voltage to it with your previously constructed circuit.

Comment: @brhans It worked properly! It did indeed fry the opto, fortunately I had spares so no harm done. Thank you for all of the replies, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: This is not a forum where you edit the title to mark it as solved.  It is a question and answer site.  To finish up a question, you accept a posted answer.  Since you found the solution, you can post an answer yourself and accept it.  If you don't do that, this thing will stay open and irritate people for years.

Comment: I'm glad you found your solution, but can I add that wiring mains (even if its only 120V) into a breadboard is *strongly discouraged*. Regardless of skill or experience, it is *incredibly easy* to create a short or shock yourself. Us electronic engineers are in short supply, please don't reduce the pool further.

Answer (score 0):

I had the 22k ohm resistor connected with both of its legs shorted together. Changed the orientation of the resistor and it worked as intended!